# Finding Coordinates of a Point in 3D with Known Distances From 3 Other Points.

Tags: geometry, 3d

trying to find Coordinates of point D
I have coordinates for A, B and C . I also have distance to D from points A, B and C.
I'm going to call distances X distance from A, Y distance from B and Z distance from C.
How can I find D's coordinates on 3D place given all those information.
Thank you in advance! 
Sorry for simplifying it.

Comment: Could you give us an example with more details to better illustrate?

Comment: Coordinates (X, Y, Z) (Distance to D)
|
A (-66, -67, -454) (42.59)
|
B (-78, -149, -340) (102.78)
|
C (687, -362, -697) (870.14) 
|
D (?, ?, ?)
I'm trying to Find D

Comment: There is more then 1 point though, so instead of asking them 1 by 1 I would like to be able to find them myself. I don't know what terms to use to search for. Also the other formulas were too complicated for me to figure out. So just a formula for 3 points would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: The Wikipedia [trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) article describes both the problem in more detail, and the exact solution. Essentially, you move to coordinates where A is at origin, B is at $(d,0,0)$ and C is at $(i, j,0)$, and solve $x$, $y$, and $z$ there. The "Preliminary and final computations" section shows how to construct that coordinate system, and how to calculate the location(s) of D in the original coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the coordinates of a point $D(x,y,z)$. Then, you need to make three equations (in order to find the three variables $x$, $y$ and $z$. Solve the system of equations and you´ll get the value of $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Construct each equation by the information given, for instance:

$$\tag {1} d_{AD}=\sqrt {(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2+(z-z_A)^2}$$

If $d_{AD}$ is the distance from $A(x_A,y_A,z_A)$ to $D(x,y,z)$

The same thing with:

$$\tag {2} d_{BD}=\sqrt {(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2+(z-z_B)^2}$$
$$\tag {3} d_{CD}=\sqrt {(x-x_C)^2+(y-y_C)^2+(z-z_C)^2}$$

Solve the system of the equations (1), (2) and (3) and find the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$

Comment: @Goodmane No problem!

Comment: It should be noted that plugging in for $d_{AD}^2-d_{BD}^2$ etc gets rid of all quadratic terms in the unknowns, leaving a linear system of equations. However, only two of those equations are independent. If distances from *four* non-coplanar points were given, this would result in a system of 3 linear equations which could be solved uniquely.

Comment: With only three distances given, if a solution point $D$ exists, then it can be mirrored across the plane through $A,B,C$, and the mirrored point $D'$ is a solution as well.

Comment: Uerr.. now how do I solve this system of equations?

Comment: @johnktejik well, with that system I didn't manage to solve it bcs it is linearly dependent. I am trying with spherical sinus because you can easily construct spherical triangles from the distances with the law of cosines. Looks very susceptible to errors if your distances come from a physical measurement process, tho.